# C# can't infer type argument type from usage when using Action

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Suppose I have such code with MonoDevelope targeting .Net 3.5:

```
public void TestTemplate<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    // pseudocode
    m_funcDict[typeof(T).GetHashCode()] += action;
}

public void TestUsage(object arg)
{
    TestTemplate(TestUsage);
}
```

And I get such error:

> Error CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   `TestTemplate(System.Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments explicitly (CS0411)
>   (Assembly-CSharp)

Is there any way I could do this without manual specify the type argument?

**What I want is just to `automatically` deduce the type.**

Comment: I need to do something with `T` in the `TestTemplate` function. Indeed I want to use this way to extract the argument info of `TestUsage`

Comment: I added some pseudocode to explain my purpose.

Comment: Why are you doing `typeof(T).GetHashCode()`? Surely `typeof(T)` is a suitable key?

Comment: @Enigmativity sort of. It is just a pseudocode to explain I want to do something with the T.

Comment: Just wondering, shouldn't there be something like `TestTemplate<XXX>(TestUsage)`?

Comment: Why don't you want to specify the type? `TestTemplate<object>(TestUsage);` seems simple enough. Or you could make `TestUsage` itself generic.

Comment: What I want is just to `automatically` deduce the type.

Comment: why don't you work with an interface? specify an interface you give it.. implement it on your classes and you always get the right class in it. possible?

Comment: Try `var t2 = TestUsage;` then you will see that the compiler doesn't even bother to deduce *ANY* automatic type, so no way to deduce the generic type automatically. The reason might be the possibility for method overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I could do this without manual specify the type argument?

Shortest answer is *NO, you cant*.

Type inference doesn't work like this. You need to convert the method `TestUsage` to appropriate Action type in order to use it as parameter for `TestTemplate`.

However in your case you can use `GetType()` to extract `Type` from the argument at run-time and use it to access the desired item in dictionary.

```
public void TestTemplate(Action<object> action,Type t)
{
    // pseudocode
    m_funcDict[t.GetHashCode()] += action;
}

public void TestUsage(object arg)
{
    Type t = arg.GetType();
    TestTemplate(TestUsage,t);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I may try this way later.